# Bi-directional migration with CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

Does anyone have any clue if it's possible to do a bi-directional migration with Core Data?  As an example, I would like to add a feature that is only supported with a newer iOS (external images) while still supporting iOS3.1.  What I was hoping to do was allow the user to export the data to the older model when they are going to an older device.

This might be a nightmare to maintain, but I was just curious if anyone has tried this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would probably be to create some kind of intermediate data format, JSON or XML based, that you could output the newer model to and write to the older one.

ALternately, you could create a data model with the new features, and a data model that only used older features, then open up store coordinators for each and copy things between the model that way.  At first that would seem easier and is really more what you were asking for, but I am very wary of trading too far outside the bounds of where countless users of Core Data users have gone before you and paved the way with their weathered bones.  Most people only have one store coordinator; never mind two pointing at different models.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I actually was able to do this by creating a data model mapping between the two versions.  This didn't automatically save external images, so then I had to create a custom policy to handle those.  Luckily, it wasn't nearly as difficult as I had imagined it would be.